# Pandas Series fill NaNs upto a certain limit only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataset "artwork.csv"
https://gitlab.com/IEA_ML_LAB/test/-/blob/80713d4823c4778d11468bcaf4a5223f6a160c88/artwork.csv

The 'year' column includes int64 and NaN.

[image]

I want to replace the first 100 NaN values with text 'no date'. I tried different methods but didn't succeed.

'year' columns has 1279 NaN values. I want to set the first 100 out of 1279 to 'no date'

[image]

The first 100 NaN values:

[image]

I try the below commands. They don't produce any errors but they don't modify the Series either:

```
df.loc[df.year.isnull(), 'year'].iloc[:100] = 'no date'
```

```
(df.loc[df.year.isnull(), 'year'].iloc[:100]).replace('NaN', 'no date', inplace=True)
```

```
(df.loc[df.year.isnull(), 'year'].iloc[:100]).transform(lambda x: 'no date')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: `df.year.iloc[:100].fillna('no date')`

Answer (score 2):

[`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) has a `limit` argument you can set to 100:

```
df['year'] = df['year'].fillna('no date', limit=100)
```

No need to call `iloc` beforehand, as that would generate an additional copy of data.

Although beware mixing strings and floats is probably not the best option here as it severely impacts performance while handling the data.